# Concatenating arrays of mutable structs

Tags: matrix, julia

Lets say I have a mutable struct:

```
mutable struct a
    x :: Float64
end
```

For whatever reason I want to concatenate a matrix and a vector of my `a`:

```
b = Matrix{a}(undef, (0, 2))
c = [a(2.), a(3.)]
vcat(b, c)    # ERROR: ArgumentError: number of columns of each array 
# must match (got (2, 1))
```

How can I add my vector `c` as a new row on the bottom of `b`?

Note: I realise that `c` should be a row vector, but the operator `'` (ie. `c'`) cannot be applied to `Vector{a}`, which is part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can do it:

```
vcat(b, reshape(c, 1, 2))
```

or

```
vcat(b, permutedims(c))
```

or

```
vcat(b, [v for _ in 1:1, v in c])
```

In particular `permutedims` is similar to `transpose` but it is not recursive (as opposed to `transpose`).

You could also create `c` as a matrix in the first place:

```
c = [a(2.) a(3.)]
```

in which case `vcat(b, c)` simply works.

Comment: Your answer is nicer. And I was 9 seconds too late :)

Comment: But, it is good to stress how to create a row matrix as this is simplest :).

Answer (score 1):

Your `c` isn't a row vector but a column vector. The following works:

```
b = Matrix{a}(undef, (0, 2))
c = [a(2.) a(3.)] # left out the comma here to generate a size (1,2) object
vcat(b, c)
```

Comment: I know that c needed to be a row vector as noted in the question. You cannot go `c'` as you would with a matrix of Float64, leaving showing how to convert `c` into a row vector as a possible solution.